# Actionable Messages sometimes are not parsed correctly

Tags: adaptive-cards, office365connectors

We've got reports that sometimes actionable messages are not displayed correctly by some clients. It doesn't matter if they message is displayed on Outlook OWA or Outlook Desktop app.

I asked one of the clients to install Actionable Message debugger app and check the diagnostics section and others. Here are some details I've managed to read off from it:

- No card is attached to this message.
- Actionable messages processing has not been performed on this message. Actionable messages are only enabled for Office 365.
- Adaptive card payload found but could not be parsed. Please validate the payload.

And diagnostics section:

```
"CardEnabledForMessage": false,
"ClientName": "OutlookWebApp",
"ClientVersion": "16.2528.7.2602797",
"InternetMessageId": "<ID>",
"Error": "EntityDocument does not exist.",
-
"AdaptiveCardPayload": {
    "found": true,
    "type": "AdaptiveCard"
},
-
"MessageCardPayload": {
    "found": false,
    "type": null
},
-
"AuthHeader": {
    "results": "<address>; dkim=none (message not signed) header.d=none;<address>; dmarc=none action=none header.from=<address>;",
    "authAs": "Internal"
}
```

Up until recently, I wasn't able to reproduce the issue on my end. During some tests, I've sent myself a test message and it has not been parsed correctly. 
When I sent another test message afterwards, it was working perfectly fine.

Of course after comparison of both messages' sources yielded that both sources were identical. Headers were a little different but mostly in time and what appears to be the server. Diagnostics and error sections from debugger are almost identical.

The method we use is SMTP ([there were some issues with EWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52076068/actionable-messages-not-displaying-regional-utf-8-characters)) and we're thinking of switching back if that causes the issue.

Is there something that can be done in regards to this issue? It's probably worth noting that the payload we send is quite 'heavy' (as in, we had to limit ourselves with the amount of data we send because we were hitting something what looked like size limit)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the script slightly makes the messages render for some users. Others had to wait some time (possibly for some OWA update?) for them to work.

So in the end nothing has been changed and it started working after some time.